# HTaccess Yii + PHP Rewrite Rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii

I'm using Yii with normal PHP for a website

My root directory

scripts (folder) -> 1.php
index.html -> this is used to refer to the website. eg: www.abcd.com

So when I need to refer to scripts, I generally do www.abcd.com/scripts/1.php

Now, I'm planning to use Yii for a project.
scripts -> 1.php
advanced
   -> frontend -> web -> index.php

So now when I open www.abcd.com  -> it should point to advanced/frontend/web/index.php and when I open www.abcd.com/scripts/1.php it should point to the same file I referred above in the root directory.

How can I do that?

Comment: Basically handle only the main page's url with yii rest, everything should be handled via normal php/htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

Place the rewrite rule for the scripts before the general rule that goes to index.php and tell apache to ignore those urls.

```
RewriteRule ^scripts/ - [L]

RewriteRule !^advanced/frontend/web /advanced/frontend/web%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/advanced/frontend/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /advanced/frontend/web/index.php [L]
```